# Perl Job controller

Tags: perl, perl-module

I have several perl scripts for data download, validation, database upload etc. I need to write a job controller who can run these scripts in specified manner.

Is there any job controller module in perl?

Answer (score 1):

There are a bunch of options and elements to what you're looking for.

Here for instance is a "job persistence engine"
http://metacpan.org/pod/Garivini

What I think you want might be more comprehensive.  You could go big with something like "bamboo" which is a continuous integration/build system.  There are several of those if you want to go down that route:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration

Or you could start with something like RabbitMQ, which bills itself as a message queuing system but has the ability to restart failed jobs and execute things in order, so it has some resilience built in, but you the actual job control software (what watches the queue and executes events?) might need to be written by you, using the Net::RabbitMQ module.  I'm not sure.

http://metacpan.org/pod/Net::RabbitMQ

Here is a (Ruby) example of using RabbitMQ to manage job queuing.
[How do I trigger a job when another completes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9776543/how-do-i-trigger-a-job-when-another-completes)